# Adding a mouse / touch helper to Qgis2threejs plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, 3d, cesium, qgis2three

Could the Qgis2threejs plugin have a mouse / touch helper window added to the output display?

Saw this [one on a Cesium display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hJqP.png) and thinking a similar helper on Qgis2threejs would make the tool more user friendly for non-GIS people.

I know working with kmz/kml files it is a pretty easy to add html linked pics for helpers, legends, title blocks, etc. and have them display on Google Earth.

You can also edit the [Controls Box](http://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs-release/3DViewer.html#controls-box)

- This feature is available with 3DViewer(dat-gui) template.

  - The controls box has:
  - layer sub menus
  - Each sub menu has:
- a check box to toggle layer visibility
- a slider to adjust layer transparency
- sub menu to control a vertically movable plane
  help button to show the about box

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, maybe not exact feature, however still useful. You would have to look into this resource [Qgis2threejs plugin](http://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs-release/3DViewer.html)

> Mouse and keyboard operation method depends on the control selected in the export settings. There is list of mouse buttons and keys in the about box. Press I key to show the box.

Comment: Is the about box editable where these type of images could be added? https://i.imgur.com/N6TEceN.png   Similar to the way html hyperlinked images are added to kmz / kml  Also, could just lay on one of the corners without needing to hit the i key.

Comment: I've updated the response to provide that information, via the controls box.